# How to split 2 connected objects with slight connection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr, connected-components

I'm working on OCR project and I face a problem that text image to be recognized may contain connected two characters so when I try to take every single character it takes the two characters as one image.
here is the code

```
BW1 = imread('test.png');
BW1 = BW1(:,:,1);
BW1=im2bw(BW1,0.9);
imshow(BW1)
patterns = bwlabel(~BW1);
patternStats = regionprops(patterns,'all');
patternNumber = size(patternStats);
imagePatternArray = cell(patternNumber);

%make cell array of pattern Matrices
for i = 1:1:patternNumber
  imageMatrix = patternStats(i).Image;
  imageMatrix = imresize(imageMatrix, [25 25]);
  imagePatternArray{i}=imageMatrix;
end
```

the original image
[image: original image]

after converting to BW
[image: processed image]

Comment: Can you upload the original image that contains all of the text?  I have some ideas, but I can't be sure that they'll work unless I have access to the original image.

Comment: No problem.  Give me a little bit.  I'm going to try some stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest you do is look directly at the colour distribution of the image itself.  Specifically, if you look at the original image, you see that there is a dominant purple in comparison to the rest of the image.  I would suggest you convert your colour image into the HSV colour space by [`rgb2hsv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html) then threshold on the hue component itself.  As such, do something like this:

```
%// Read directly from StackOverflow
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu92r.png');

%// Convert image into HSV
hsv = rgb2hsv(im2double(im));

%// Threshold hue component by 0.75
out = im2bw(hsv(:,:,1), 0.75);

%// Show the image
imshow(out);
```

If you take a look at the Hue component in the HSV colour space, purple colours are situated between 0.6 and 0.8.  I chose 0.75 to be safe.

We get:

[image]

The output is quite small, so let me resize the image by a factor of 4 with bilinear interpolation:

[image]

You will see some aliasing due to the upsampling, but ignore that.  I wanted to show you that each letter is certainly separated.  You can process the letters individually.

Comment: this looks good for purple characters only, my project should work with all text colors.

Comment: Find the average hue of any colours that have a nonzero hue and use that as a threshold. Another idea would be to find the min and max values, and go up 75% of the way... Or something like that. Either way, if your images are colour, definitely take advantage of the hue.

Comment: I tried another threshold for im2bw and it worked for this image, but for other images it didn't work

Comment: Obviously you'll need to make it adaptive. Look up the graythresh command

Comment: Please upload some more images so I can test